# Fusing traversals

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

The [Traversable Paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) gives an example on page 18-19 of fusing monoidal and monadic traversals which sounds really interesting but I'm confused by their LaTex.

```
cciBody :: Char -> Count a
wciBody :: Char -> (|M| (State Bool) DotInASquare Count) a
```

With the amazing result that:

```
(traverse cciBody) xInACircle (traverse wciBody)
```

Is the same as:

```
traverse (cciBody xInACircle wciBody)
```

I think the type of that result is:

```
Count XInASquare (|M| (State Bool) DotInASquare Count) [a]
```

But not 100% sure. Could someone who speaks Emoji tell me how it should look in Haskell?

### Update

I think xInACircle might be an infix `sequenceA`. The types kind of match up. Or maybe it's just `(,)` which is an instance of `Traversable`. It's definitely not `<*>` even though the result looks a bit like `t (x <*> y) = t x <*> t y` but they don't use a Wingding for `<*>` in the paper.

### Update 2

The type of xInACircle is (Functor m, Functor n) ⇒ (a → m b) → (a → n b) → (a → (m XInASquare n) b). Remind you of anything? Not me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting confused about operators used in type signatures. Basically, the same rules from Haskell syntax hold for these: first priority is parentheses, second priority is "application", last priority is "operators". So just as you might write:

```
f 3 + g 4
```

[which in mathematical terms we'd write as *f*(3) + *g*(4)], in Haskell there is a flag to enable infix type operators (`-XTypeOperators`) beginning with colons, so that you can write an expression like `f :: a :* b -> b :* [a]` in place of `f :: Star a b -> Star b [a]`. It's just an alternative syntax for a parametric type constructor with at least two parameters. (I guess since `->` is already an infix type constructor this is hardly news.) We can also write these as `Comp a b` and `Prod a b`.

The up-arrows and down-arrows are functions defined within the paper as part of a type class, but I don't like all of the pragmas that we need in order for Haskell to actually accept those functions, so I'm going to explicate them in this code. Here are all of the relevant definitions as a valid Haskell file using `Comp` and `Prod` instead of their operators:

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative, (<$>), (<*>), pure, WrappedMonad(..), Const(..))
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy (State, state, runState)
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.Monoid (Monoid(..))

instance Monoid Integer where
    mempty = 0
    mappend = (+)

-- chained functors
newtype Comp m n a = Comp {runComp :: m (n a)}
instance (Functor m, Functor n) => Functor (Comp m n) where
    fmap f = Comp . fmap (fmap f) . runComp
instance (Applicative m, Applicative n) => Applicative (Comp m n) where
    pure = Comp . pure . pure
    Comp mnf <*> Comp mnx = Comp ((<*>) <$> mnf <*> mnx)

-- outer product of functors
data Prod m n a = Prod {pfst :: m a, psnd :: n a}
instance (Functor m, Functor n) => Functor (Prod m n) where
    fmap f (Prod ma na) = Prod (fmap f ma) (fmap f na)
instance (Applicative m, Applicative n) => Applicative (Prod m n) where
    pure x = Prod (pure x) (pure x)
    Prod mf nf <*> Prod mx nx = Prod (mf <*> mx) (nf <*> nx)

-- page 19,20

type Count = Const Integer
count :: a -> Count b
count _ = Const 1

cciBody :: Char -> Count a
cciBody = count

cci :: String -> Count [a]
cci = traverse cciBody

test :: Bool -> Integer
test b = if b then 1 else 0

lciBody :: Char -> Count a
lciBody c = Const (test (c == '\n'))

lci :: String -> Count [a]
lci = traverse lciBody

wciBody :: Char -> Comp (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count a
wciBody c = Comp (fmap Const (WrapMonad $ state $ updateState c)) where
    updateState :: Char -> Bool -> (Integer, Bool)
    updateState c w = let s = not (isSpace c) in (test (not w && s), s)

wci :: String -> Comp (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count [a]
wci = traverse wciBody

runWci :: String -> Integer
runWci s = fst $ runState (fmap getConst $ unwrapMonad $ runComp $ wci s) False
```

If you're not clear where any functions come from I've restricted the imports up-top, so look up there (or use Hoogle) to find their definitions.

The **operator** you're calling `xInACircle` is an operator which takes an `a -> m b` and an `a -> n b` and produces a function `a -> Prod m n b`. This product type contains both results of both applicatives `m` and `n`. Once you understand the x-in-a-square type you'll understand the x-in-a-circle operator. Basically unlike the `(Monoid m) => Applicative ((,) m)` instance, which only `fmap`s and `<*>`s over its second argument, the `Prod` of two abstract-functors is a pair-functor which `fmap`s and `<*>`s over both its arguments. It is the pair `(m a, n a)` where both `m` and `n` are applicative.